# The most effective way to find the input for a given label?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a library that doesn't provide an easy way to uniquely id each input. It does however put a unique "text" element inside the corresponding label.

So far this works to get my label by text

```
$("label:contains('Name')")
```

But ... how can I take this and get the next available input (after this element) w/ the least performance impact using jQuery?

**Update**

here is the html I'm working with -thanks for all the help!

```
<label id="ember386" class="ember-view control-label">
<script id="metamorph-19-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Name<script id="metamorph-19-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></label>
<script id="metamorph-20-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<input id="ember388" class="ember-view ember-text-field form-control">
```

**Update 2**

This worked! thanks to Robert for the help!

```
$("label:contains('Name')").siblings('input').first()
```

Comment: I just noticed that your HTML above contains a duplicate ID of "ember386" on the label and the input. Is the attribute in the label actually a "for" attribute by chance? If not this code is invalid as IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eek... for `<label>` to be useful it should have a 'for' attribute that tells you the ID of the input it is associated with.  Otherwise the label really isn't doing it's intended job of enabling accessibility.  Ideally, you'd grab the label and then do `$('#' + theLabel.attr('for'))`.  But to answer your question of finding the next input, that should just be `theLabel.siblings('input').first()` though this will obviously break if your DOM changes such that labels aren't before the corresponding input.

Comment: I tried .next('input') but it always returns [] for some odd reason

Comment: To clarify the "isn't doing it's intended job" line there is an exception to this.  By default (and as part of the spec) a label can also associate with a control just by wrapping the input element.  This is very common when wrapping an input and the text for a radio button or checkbox control to increase the hit target for usability.

Comment: ok updated my answer to be correct but the point about this being a poor use of `label` still stands :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the example below to resolve your issue.

```
$("label").each(function(){
if($(this).html() == "THIS" || $(this).html().indexOf("THIS") != -1){
//Do Something
}
});
```

Comment: The OP has already found the label via `$("label:contains('Name')")`; there's no reason to iterate over every `label`.

Comment: ...and if there were this would be a pretty horrific way of doing it